# Shopping a book and doing a subtraction

Tags: c#, sql

I use these following codes for buying a book and ..... 
In the `TextBox` when every time I type the number of sold books it updates a new `TextBox` value in the database. It must do a subtraction every time that books sells. But, it updates the new values.

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
        {
            sql = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PC-PC\PC;Initial Catalog=Anbar;Integrated Security=True");
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Goods", sql);
            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = sql;
            cmd.CommandText = ("Update Goods set Buy =@Buy, Remain =@Remain where GoodsNumber =@GoodsNumber");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Buy", Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GoodsNumber", Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remain", Convert.ToInt32(comboBox3.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));
            sql.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sql.Close();
            fill();
        }
    }
```

It should show the remain of total Books.

Comment: Add a using statement around your sql connection and command objects.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: will using statement solve this problem? how?

Comment: Ali, what is in Combobox3.Text ? also why you have an adapter, you are not filling it any where? I believe you have to first get the value of remaining books from the database and then subtract it from textbox value and then update the database

Comment: @aliprogrammer, no, it will not.  P.Brian.Mackey is just trying to offer some helpful advice.

Comment: No, its best practice for cleaning up external resources.  Are you saying the user interface isn't showing the remainder properly?  I don't see any obvious problems with the update statement.  If I'm guessing correctly comboBox3.Text should be updated and its not happening here.  `comboBox3.Text = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox3.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text)`

Comment: @Habib.OSU combobox3.text is total available books which should subtract from textbox value. but everytime it subtract with the new textbox value

Comment: @aliprogrammer, What do you mean by new Value ? isn't that its suppose to do ? you enter a value in textbox and you want to subtract it from remaining count ?

Comment: Yes. For example we have 100 books. person1 will buy 20 books. so the remain book is 80. after that person2 will buy 30 books so remain books must be 80 - 30 =50. but it shows 70 books means total havent change 100 - 30 = 70. how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is that you don't update `comboBox3` after you update remaining count in database.

Btw why you use combo box for this? Also there are very confusing column names in database: Buy, GoodsNumber and Remain. It's really hard to guess what data stored there. Consider such names as ProductId, Name and Quantity.

If I would implement something like that, I'd started from loading products to combobox:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    productsComboBox.DataSource = GetAllProducts();
    productsComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
    productsComboBox.ValueMember = "Id";
}

private IList<Product> GetAllProducts()
{
    List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

    // I use ConfigurationManager from System.Configuration.dll 
    // to read connection strings from App.config
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["anbar"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Products";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            products.Add(new Product() { Id = (int)reader["Id"],
                                         Name = (string)reader["Name"],
                                         Quantity = (int)reader["Quantity"] });
        }
    }
    return products;
}
```

Product is simple class:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

When selected product changed, display its details:

```
private void ProductsComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Product product = productsComboBox.SelectedItem as Product;
    qtyTextBox.Text = product.Quantity.ToString();
    // I use NumericUpDown control to input numbers
    // Minimum is set to 1
    qtyToSellNumericUpDown.Maximum = product.Quantity;
}
```

And last - when I entered quantity to sell (1..current quantity), I do following:

```
private void ButtonSell_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Product product = productsComboBox.SelectedItem as Product;
    int qtyToSell = (int)qtyToSellNumericUpDown.Value;
    SellProduct(product, qtyToSell);
    product.Quantity -= qtyToSell; // update product
    qtyTextBox.Text = product.Quantity.ToString(); // update current quantity 
}

private void SellProduct(Product product, int qtyToSell)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["anbar"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string query = "UPDATE Products SET Quantity = @Quantity WHERE Id = @Id";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", product.Id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", product.Quantity - qtyToSell);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Thats it. Yes, there are many things to improve, but this little sample works.

UPDATE: How to add connection string to App.Config

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="anbar" 
         connectionString="Data Source=PC-PC\PC;Initial Catalog=Anbar;Integrated Security=True"                 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```